# Trigger debugs when uploading data with python?

Tags: apex, trigger, python

Is it possible to do get trigger debugs when uploading data with python? I haven't been able to find the debug logs whenever I upload the data with python bulk.

Comment: Is the data load successful and still you are seeing the error or the data is not getting updated at all?

Comment: I'm not talking about seeing whether it's successful or not - I'm just trying to see if it's possible to see the System.debug outputs that I have in my code

Comment: Ideally it should check the debug logs levels that you have set.

Comment: I've set it to finest for all of them. Do you know where I would find them if they were being saved salesforce side?I looked around for debug logs but could never find them in my sidebar

Comment: Did you set up a user debug trace using Setup > Debug Logs?

Comment: Set up the debug traces with which user you are doing this upload to Salesforce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the debug logs for a trigger ( since the dataload process will take place under the context of the Admin User ), you have to create a log level in the Developer Console. Change your log levels as:

Developer Console -> Debug ( menu on the top-left corner ) -> Change Log Levels

A popup will be shown that will contain the option 'Change and Trigger Trace Overrides'. Click add to add your trigger in the menu, specify start time, end time and a log level and you shall the debug logs generated for your trigger.

[image]

Comment: So I THINK I've got it set up correctly. Where should I see the debug logs if that's the case?

Comment: If the red mark in front of the name of your trigger turns green it's set up correctly, you'd have figured this out already. To see the logs of your process, at the bottom of your screen, you'll see multiple tabs, select 'Logs'. After your process is complete, you'll see logs regarding that.